# Rails - How to declare attr_accessible for multiple roles without duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to declare attr_accessible for multiple roles without a ton of duplication?

If I have several user roles, and each role is allowed to edit a different subset of attributes, here's what my attr_accessible declaration looks like:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :active, :as => :admin
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :as => :manager
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :as => :guest
```

I'd like to either

- A) define an array of accessible attributes that can be shared among
  different roles or
- B) define an array of roles than can access the same
  attributes

Is this possible?

Comment: What authorization framework are you using that allows you to restrict attr_accessible on roles? That isn't standard Rails AFAIK.

Comment: Oh - I'm using Rails 3.1, so it might be a newer feature.  The :as argument shows up in the MassAssignmentSecurity module (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ruby code is still just ruby code... and is thus infinitely hackable. eg

```
ROLES = [:admin, :manager, :support, :user, :guest]
ACTIVE_ROLES = [:admin, :support]
ROLES.each do |role|
   fields = [:first_name, :last_name]
   fields += [:active] if ACTIVE_ROLES.include?(role)
   attr_accessible *fields, :as => role
end
```

Comment: For Rails 3 apps, see the answer by @AdrianMacneil

Answer (score 44):

I just spent a long time trying to figure out the best way to do this. It seemed strange that the rails folk would expect you to duplicate a whole bunch of code!

After some digging around in the rails source, it turns out you can simply pass an array to assign attributes to multiple roles at once (:default being the default Active Record role)

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :as => [ :default, :admin ]    
attr_accessible :featured, :as => :admin
```

No messy ruby arrays in your model!

Comment: Just like to say that this is prettier and readable code than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes it is... but it's also Rails3-specific... and this question was asked some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like:

```
COMMON_FIELDS = [:first_name, :last_name]

attr_accessible COMMON_FIELDS | [:active, :as => :admin]
attr_accessible COMMON_FIELDS | [:as => :manager]
attr_accessible COMMON_FIELDS | [:as => :guest]
```

Another possible way (untested):

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
ADMIN_ACCESSIBLE   = [:active]
MANAGER_ACCESSIBLE = []
GUEST_ACCESSIBLE   = []

protected

def mass_assignment_authorizer
  if role == :all
    self.class.protected_attributes
  else
    super + (eval("#{role}_accessible".upcase) || [])
  end
end
```

Comment: Note, that it works only with Ruby 1.9 – [:as => :admin] will cause syntax error